# Is this a standard way to render a component?

Tags: reactjs

I've come across the code below as a way to render a component based on the truthy/falsiness of a state variable. (Although I'm aware SO is a platform for solving problems, I feel I'm still within my right to ask the following question (for reasons I post at the end)). Is this way of rendering a component/tag common/advised?

```js
//a functional component
return (
  <>
  {stateVariable && <ChildComponent>}
  </>
)
```

As I see:

- Potential benefit: doesn't involve rendering tag in a function with vanilla js.
- Potential drawback: can make the return statement long & messy.

**Why I think this is a valid SO question:** I recall a previous question where a heavily voted answer explained to me the function I was using, while valid, was deprecated. While this question's answer might be subject to opinion, it could save me from using deprecated code that works today but might not work tomorrow.

Comment: I guess it depends on *what* is doing the `return`. Can you provide a more complete code example?

Comment: @DrewReese Like as in a functional component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code

```
return (
  {stateVariable && <ChildComponent>}
)
```

alone isn't valid JSX as a react component return as components must return JSX or `null` to indicate rendering nothing.

However, the syntax ***IS*** valid if conditionally rendering *some* nested UI, i.e.

```
return (
  <>
    <h1>My Header Text</h1>
    {stateVariable && <ChildComponent>}
  </>
);
```

In the second example the component is returning a single JSX node and internally conditionally rendering `ChildComponent`. If `stateVariable` is false then it will be ignored by React.

[Inline If with Logical && Operator](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator) vs [Preventing Component from Rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#preventing-component-from-rendering)

Comment: I forgot to add the empty tag. I've edited the question to show that. Thanks for the links, will have a read

Comment: @tonitone120 Then, yes, standard way to conditionally render a component. If the real code is just like the example snippet (just the single component) then I would say returning `null` is the correct answer, otherwise the logical and is what you want.